# ¿Etiquetas de motores de almacenamiento (Base de datos)?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Me he encontrado con [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131392/que-me-recomiendan-para-realizar-backup-de-bases-de-datos-muy-pesadas), para la cual es necesario saber qué motor de almacenamiento tiene trabajando (ejemplo: MyISAM o InnoDB) en su base de datos MySQL para poder responder correctamente.

Me he fijado que en SO existen este tipo de etiquetas.

La pregunta es:

¿Se debe especificar qué motor de almacenamiento usa la base de datos en la pregunta o se puede crear una etiqueta de los motores de almacenamiento para poder acceder a esas preguntas por la etiqueta?

Comment: Si el motor es relevante para la pregunta, en mi opinión si se debería especificar una etiqueta para ello.